# Obtain the name of a recently added drive in linux by using diff awk grep and regular expressions

Tags: regex, linux, awk, grep

In an attempt to get the name of the drive that was just added to the system, I am checking the difference between two files that are created by **cat** /proc/partitions before and after adding the drive.  I am looking for the name of the drive without the numeric suffix of the partition number.

```
cat /proc/partitions > /mnt/HD_a2/tempFiles/file1
... add some additional drives to the system
cat /proc/partitions > /mnt/HD_a2/tempFiles/file2

diff /mnt/HD_a2/tempFiles/file1 /mnt/HD_a2/tempFiles/file2
```

When I run the diff command it returns:

```
16a17,18
>    8    32    7816704 sdc
>    8    33    7816688 sdc1
```

When the awk is added to get the values from the 5th column on the lines that are prefixed with '>'

```
 diff /mnt/HD_a2/tempFiles/file1 /mnt/HD_a2/tempFiles/file2 |  awk '">" { print $5 }'
```

the return is:

```
-- blank line is returned here--
sdc
sdc1
```

in an attempt to return only 'sdc' the grep command  was added,

```
diff /mnt/HD_a2/tempFiles/file1 /mnt/HD_a2/tempFiles/file2 |  awk '">" { print $5 }' | grep ^[A-Za-z]+$
```

but when I run the command line I get no output at all.

if the grep command is replaced with

```
 grep ^[A-Za-z]*$
```

the return excludes the sdc1, but still returns a blank line before sdc

I someone could explain the error in my syntax, or provide a better way to get the name of a recently added new drive, I would appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
diff /mnt/HD_a2/tempFiles/file1 /mnt/HD_a2/tempFiles/file2 \
|  awk  '">" && NF>2 && $5 !~ /[0-9]$/{ print $5 }'
```

output

```
sdc
```

The NF means number of fields, you might want to change that to a higher number, like 4. You can use this to skip empty lines, or lines without enough worthwhile data.

The `$5 !~ /[0-9]$/` says ignore lines ending in numbers.

The `&&`s means all of these conditions must be true before printinng field `$5`.

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

You probably wanted `/^>/`, not `">"` at the beginning of awk script. Also, try `grep '^[[:alpha:]]\+$'` to skip empty lines.

But if this is supposed to be a reliable part of device detection, please read about udev scripts. It's fairly easy to hook into events such as "block device connected" and run custom scripts then. It's probably less hacky than parsing the partitions file.